# @Composable function inside onClick event - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I try show AlertDialog when press a button.
For AlertDialog i have a composable function - showDialog.
It is clear that this function calls a dialog.
I have another composable function which displays some window with text and buttons.
When the button is clicked, I want to call a function that stores the AlertDialog.

AlertDialog body:

```
fun monthDialog() {

val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

if (openDialog.value) {
    AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = {
            openDialog.value = false
        },
        title = {
            Text(text = "Title")
        },
        text = {
            Text(
                "This area typically contains the supportive text " +
                        "which presents the details regarding the Dialog's purpose."
            )
        },
        buttons = {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 8.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    onClick = { openDialog.value = false }
                ) {
                    Text("Dismiss")
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

first I tried the simplest solution that came to my mind:

```
IconButton(onClick = monthDialog())
```

and got error (@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function)

after i tried a normal trigger using mutablestateof and following condition:

```
val showDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false)}
if(showDialog.value == true) monthDialog()
```

and put some like this into onClick event:

```
monthHeader(onClick = {showDialog.value = !showDialog.value})
```

and this is work....but ugly and badly.
for a first time this is worf fine. but after the first click, I need to click two more times to trigger that event again.

button code snippet:

```
fun Calendar (){
//...

val showDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false)}
if(showDialog.value == true) monthDialog()

Card(
){
    Column(){
            IconButton(onClick ={
                monthDialog() // error here
                //showDialog.value = !showDialog.value
            }
    }
}
```

after few hours for searching in google
i try my own solution

```
val clicked = remember { mutableStateOf(false)}
val showDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false)}

if(showDialog.value) monthDialog()
else if(clicked.value) monthDialog()

Card(){
    Column(){
        monthHeader(onClick = {
            clicked.value = showDialog.value
            showDialog.value = !clicked.value
        })
    }
}
```

but in my opinion this is crutch/kludge

Comment: What is your problem here? Does it work?

Comment: @Marat i edit my post. please look again

Comment: why you don't just use `monthHeader(onClick = {showDialog.value = true})` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leaving a better solution here (imho):

[Hoist the state](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting) of your dialog.

```
@Composable
fun MonthDialog(onClose: () -> Unit) {
    AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = onClose,
        title = {
            Text(text = "Title")
        },
        text = {
            Text(
                "This area typically contains the supportive text " +
                        "which presents the details regarding the Dialog's purpose."
            )
        },
        buttons = {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 8.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    onClick = onClose
                ) {
                    Text("Dismiss")
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

Noticed that I removed the state from this component and make it stateless. This component will just notify when the dialog is closed.

Now you can call the dialog like this:

```
var showDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
if (showDialog) {
    MonthDialog(onClose = { showDialog = false })
}
Card {
    MonthHeader( // use upper case for naming your composables
        onClick = {
            showDialog = true
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also use `Modifier` / `PointerInputScope`:

```
modifier = Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
    detectTapGestures(
        onPress = { },
        onTap = { },
        onDoubleTap = { },
        onLongPress = { }
    )
```